# All is working except if($_POST['submit']=='Update')

Tags: php, mysql

I have a working registration and login system. I am trying to create a form where a user can add product registration info (via mysql update). I can't seem to get the db to actually update the fields. What am I missing here?!?

```
<?php 

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);

require 'connect.php';
require 'functions.php';
// Those two files can be included only if INCLUDE_CHECK is defined


session_name('tzLogin');
// Starting the session

session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);
// Making the cookie live for 2 weeks

session_start();

if($_SESSION['id'] && !isset($_COOKIE['tzRemember']) && !$_SESSION['rememberMe'])
{
    // If you are logged in, but you don't have the tzRemember cookie (browser restart)
    // and you have not checked the rememberMe checkbox:

    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    // Destroy the session
}


if(isset($_GET['logoff']))
{
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    header("Location: index_login3.php");
    exit;
}

if($_POST['submit']=='Login')
{
    // Checking whether the Login form has been submitted

    $err = array();
    // Will hold our errors


    if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
        $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';

    if(!count($err))
    {
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $_POST['password'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $_POST['rememberMe'] = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];

        // Escaping all input data

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM electrix_users WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='".md5($_POST['password'])."'"));

        if($row['usr'])
        {
            // If everything is OK login

            $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
            $_SESSION['first'] = $row['first'];
            $_SESSION['last'] = $row['last'];
            $_SESSION['address1'] = $row['address1'];
            $_SESSION['address2'] = $row['address2'];
            $_SESSION['city'] = $row['city'];
            $_SESSION['state'] = $row['state'];
            $_SESSION['zip'] = $row['zip'];
            $_SESSION['country'] = $row['country'];
            $_SESSION['product1'] = $row['product1'];
            $_SESSION['serial1'] = $row['serial1'];
            $_SESSION['product2'] = $row['product2'];
            $_SESSION['serial2'] = $row['serial2'];
            $_SESSION['product3'] = $row['product3'];
            $_SESSION['serial3'] = $row['serial3'];
            $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];

            // Store some data in the session

            setcookie('tzRemember',$_POST['rememberMe']);

        }


        else $err[]='Wrong username and/or password!';
    }

    if($err)
    $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    // Save the error messages in the session

    header("Location: index_login3.php");
    exit;

}
else if($_POST['submit']=='Register')
{
    // If the Register form has been submitted

    $err = array();

    if(strlen($_POST['username'])<4 || strlen($_POST['username'])>32)
    {
        $err[]='Your username must be between 3 and 32 characters!';
    }

    if(preg_match('/[^a-z0-9\-\_\.]+/i',$_POST['username']))
    {
        $err[]='Your username contains invalid characters!';
    }

    if(!checkEmail($_POST['email']))
    {
        $err[]='Your email is not valid!';
    }

    if(!count($err))
    {
        // If there are no errors

        $pass = substr(md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].microtime().rand(1,100000)),0,6);
        // Generate a random password

        $_POST['email'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $_POST['first'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first']);
        $_POST['last'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['last']);
        $_POST['address1'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address1']);
        $_POST['address2'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address2']);
        $_POST['city'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
        $_POST['state'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['state']);
        $_POST['zip'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['zip']);
        $_POST['country'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);
        // Escape the input data


        mysql_query("   INSERT INTO electrix_users(usr,pass,email,first,last,address1,address2,city,state,zip,country,regIP,dt) 
                        VALUES(

                            '".$_POST['username']."',
                            '".md5($pass)."',
                            '".$_POST['email']."',
                            '".$_POST['first']."',
                            '".$_POST['last']."',
                            '".$_POST['address1']."',
                            '".$_POST['address2']."',
                            '".$_POST['city']."',
                            '".$_POST['state']."',
                            '".$_POST['zip']."',
                            '".$_POST['country']."',
                            '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',
                            NOW()

                        )");

        if(mysql_affected_rows($link)==1)
        {
            send_mail(  'noreply@electrixpro.com',
                        $_POST['email'],
                        'Your New Electrix User Password',
                        'Thank you for registering at www.electrixpro.com. Your password is: '.$pass);

            $_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']='We sent you an email with your new password!';
        }
        else $err[]='This username is already taken!';
    }

    if(count($err))
    {
        $_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    }   

    header("Location: index_login3.php");
    exit;
}

if($_POST['submit']=='Update')

{   

    {
      mysql_query(" UPDATE electrix_users(product1,serial1,product2,serial2,product3,serial3) WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}' 
              VALUES(

              '".$_POST['product1']."',
              '".$_POST['serial1']."',
              '".$_POST['product2']."',
              '".$_POST['serial2']."',
              '".$_POST['product3']."',
              '".$_POST['serial3']."',                          

          )");          

        if(mysql_affected_rows($link)==1)
        {
            $_SESSION['msg']['upd-success']='Thank you for registering your Electrix product';
        }
        else $err[]='So Sad!';
    }

    if(count($err))
    {
        $_SESSION['msg']['upd-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    }   

    header("Location: index_login3.php");
    exit;

}

if($_SESSION['msg'])
{
    // The script below shows the sliding panel on page load

    $script = '
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){

            $("div#panel").show();
            $("#toggle a").toggle();
        });

    </script>';

}
?>
```

Here are the forms:

```
   <!-- Panel -->
<div id="toppanel">
    <div id="panel">
        <div class="content clearfix">
            <div class="left">
                <h1>My Electrix Account </h1>
                <p class="grey">View and edit your contact information and product registrations</p>
            </div>


            <?php

            if(!$_SESSION['id']):

            ?>

            <div class="left">
                <!-- Login Form -->
                <form class="clearfix" action="" method="post">
                    <h1>Member Login</h1>

                    <?php

                        if($_SESSION['msg']['login-err'])
                        {
                            echo '<div class="err">'.$_SESSION['msg']['login-err'].'</div>';
                            unset($_SESSION['msg']['login-err']);
                        }
                    ?>

                    <label class="grey" for="username">Username:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="password" name="password" id="password" size="23" />
                    <label><input name="rememberMe" id="rememberMe" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" /> &nbsp;Remember me</label>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="bt_login" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="left right">            
                <!-- Register Form -->
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <h1>Not a member yet? Sign Up!</h1>     

                    <?php

                        if($_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'])
                        {
                            echo '<div class="err">'.$_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'].'</div>';
                            unset($_SESSION['msg']['reg-err']);
                        }

                        if($_SESSION['msg']['reg-success'])
                        {
                            echo '<div class="success">'.$_SESSION['msg']['reg-success'].'</div>';
                            unset($_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']);
                        }
                    ?>

                    <label class="grey" for="username">Username*:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="email">Email*:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="email" id="email" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="first">First Name:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="first" id="first" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="last">Last Name:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="last" id="last" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="address1">Address line 1:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="address1" id="address1" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="address2">Address line 2:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="address2" id="address2" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="city">City:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="city" id="city" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="state">State/Province:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="state" id="state" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="zip">Zip/Postal Code:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="zip" id="zip" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="country">Country:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="country" id="country" size="23" />
                    <p>
                    <label>A password will be e-mailed to you.</label>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="bt_register" />
                    </p>
                </form>
            </div>

            <?php

            else:

            ?>


            <div class="left">

            <h1>User Information</h1>            

            <p>
            <?php echo $_SESSION['first']; ?>
            <?php echo $_SESSION['last']; ?><br />
            <?php echo $_SESSION['address1']; ?>
            <?php echo $_SESSION['address2']; ?><br />
            <?php echo $_SESSION['city']; ?>,
            <?php echo $_SESSION['state']; ?>
            <?php echo $_SESSION['zip']; ?><br />
            <?php echo $_SESSION['country']; ?>
            </p>
            <p>Email: <?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?></p>
            <p><a href="downloads.php">Downloads</a></p>
            <a href="?logoff">Log off</a>

            </div>

            <div class="left right">

                <!-- Product Registration Form -->

                <form class="clearfix" action="" method="post">
                    <h1>Product Registration</h1>

                    <?php

                        if($_SESSION['msg']['upd-err'])
                        {
                            echo '<div class="err">'.$_SESSION['msg']['upd-err'].'</div>';
                            unset($_SESSION['msg']['upd-err']);
                        }

                        if($_SESSION['msg']['upd-success'])
                        {
                            echo '<div class="success">'.$_SESSION['msg']['upd-success'].'</div>';
                            unset($_SESSION['msg']['upd-success']);
                        }
                    ?>

                    <label class="grey" for="product1">Product 1:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="product1" id="product1" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['product1']; ?>" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="serial1">Serial 1:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="serial1" id="serial1" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['serial1']; ?>" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="product2">Product 2:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="product2" id="product2" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['product2']; ?>" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="serial2">Serial 2:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="serial2" id="serial2" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['serial2']; ?>" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="product3">Product 3:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="product3" id="product3" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['product3']; ?>" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="serial3">Serial 3:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="serial3" id="serial3" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['serial3']; ?>" size="23" />
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" class="bt_login" />
                </form>

            </div>

            <?php
            endif;
            ?>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /login -->  



    <!-- The tab on top --> 
    <div class="tab">
        <ul class="login">
            <li class="left">&nbsp;</li>
            <li>Hello <?php echo $_SESSION['usr'] ? $_SESSION['usr'] : 'Guest';?>!</li>
            <li class="sep">|</li>
            <li id="toggle">
                <a id="open" class="open" href="#"><?php echo $_SESSION['id']?'Open Panel':'Log In | Register';?></a>
                <a id="close" style="display: none;" class="close" href="#">Close Panel</a>         
            </li>
            <li class="right">&nbsp;</li>
        </ul> 
    </div> <!-- / top -->

</div> <!--panel -->
```

Comment: Can you show us your form?  at least the submit part of it

Comment: Aren't you getting any errors? Your UPDATE SQL isn't valid.

Comment: Your code, as written, is vulnerable to SQL injection. You might want to fix that by not inserting `$_POST` values directly into queries.

Comment: @Amber he isnt, he is running the values of POST through `mysql_real_escape_string` first.

Comment: @nathanjosiah Not if the submit value is `Update`. The escaping stuff is all only in the first `if` block.

Comment: Hi All, thank you for the comments and answers. I am new to php and basically following tutorials and trying to adapt them to my needs. This is the login system I found: http://tutorialzine.com/2009/10/cool-login-system-php-jquery/ All works as described so far, I added some db fields and displayed user info after login. Now I want to let users update their information. I am starting with product registration but eventually I want to let users update all their info. 
Here is the page in progress http://electrixpro.com/electrix_new/index_login3.php

Comment: I just created a test account: 
user: testing
pass: 4d9487

Answer (score 0):

Your update query is way off.   You need to do it in the form of

```
UPDATE `tablename` 
SET col1=`value`,col2=`val2`
WHERE wherecol=`whereval`
```

change your query and see if that helps.

your query should be

```
UPDATE electrix_users
SET 
    product1= $_POST['product1'],
    serial1 = $_POST['serial1'],
    product2 = $_POST['product2'],
    serial2 = $_POST['serial2'],
    product3 = $_POST['product3'],
    serial3 = $_POST['serial3']
WHERE usr=$_POST['username']
```

However you should always clean for sql injection on any user entered data.  I did not do this in the example as this is something you should do in your own way.  This example is given to you as an example and does not prevent any kind of sql injection as it stands now.

ALWAYS DO WHAT YOU CAN TO PREVENT SQL INJECTION!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That just gives me a server error. I posted the link to the page in question in a comment above. The insert form and registration forms are working, why is the update form not working? –

Comment: @user1319909 I do not see an update form there.  Where is it.  If it requires me to sign up for the site to see it, Im sorry but I can not not help out.  I do not sign up on peoples site to help solve issues.

Comment: I posted a test account in a comment above: username: testing ; pass: 4d9487

Comment: And I just added the 3 forms in my question above. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @user1319909 Your update form does not have a input field of username.  Your update statement using $_POST['username']  Should this be $_SESSION['username'].  as it stands now the update query does not know which row to update so it will not update any row.

Comment: Thank you. That was not the only issue. I had to SELECT usr as well if submit update. I found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893332/changing-user-password-in-php-and-mysql